# What is the combinator of a image assigned to a class?

Tags: html, css

I have defined a style like this:

```
.entry-content img, .entry-content img a {
   background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #d2d2d2;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #d2d2d2;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border-color:#555;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
}
```

This will make all images added to the content area to have a border, border radius, shadow, etc. by default.

But I want to be able to insert images without these attributes.

So my idea (I don't know if there is a better one) is to create a class that can isolate that. But there is a problem. If I assign a class to an image, by putting it into a div, I am not sure if I should write it like

```
.entry-content img withoutBorder, .entry-content img a withoutBorder {
}
```

or like

```
.entry-content withoutBorder img, .entry-content withoutBorder img a {
}
```

I have tried both and none make any difference and the image continues to have the attributes.

how do I do that in the easiest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you arrange classes and elements like that in css, you're actually specifying their order in the DOM tree you wish to target/style - as an example:

```css
.entry-content a img{
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #d2d2d2;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #d2d2d2;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom:30px;
  border-radius:10px;
  border-color:#555;
  border-width:1px;
  border-style:solid;
  min-height:50px;
  min-width:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
  <a href="#">
   <img src="">
  </a>
</div>
```

In the HTML part you can see that:

- `img` is a child of `a`
- `a` is a child of `.entry-content`

In the css part I'm specifying the same, by showing that "*inside `.entry-content` target `a` and inside `a`, target `img`*". In other words, it's specifying the order of the DOM tree and showing which are the parents and which are the children.

When adding a class you have to prefix it with `.` (a dot) in the css to target it.

Please also note that I've changed the HTML a bit, so that the anchor (`<a>`) surrounds the `<img>` rather than having the anchor within the `img` tag.

To change the styling for some images you will probably have to add a class indeed. This can be like so:

```css
.entry-content a img{
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #d2d2d2;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #d2d2d2;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom:30px;
  border-radius:10px;
  border-color:#555;
  border-width:1px;
  border-style:solid;
  min-height:50px;
  min-width:50px;
}
.entry-content a img.withoutborder{
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="withoutborder" src="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: `.entry-content a img.withoutborder` or ´.entry-content img a.withoutborder`? You appear to have inverted the order... is it ok?

Comment: THANKS. IT IS WORKING!

Comment: @SpaceDog yeah I inverted it as you cannot/shouldn't place the anchor tag inside the `img` tag, which is what we're implying in the structure of the css selector otherwise, by specifying `.entry-content img a`. Also, writing `a.withoutborder` means that the browser should look for an achor tag with the class name `withoutborder` - which isn't the case here :) Glad to hear it works though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS3 [`not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot) operator

```
.entry-content img:not(.withoutBorder), .entry-content img a:not(.withoutBorder) {
}
```

```css
.entry-content img:not(.no-border),
.entry-content img a:not(.no-border) {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" />
</div>
with border radius

<br />
<div class="entry-content">
    <img class="no-border" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" />
</div>
without border radius


<h2>Image inside anchor tag</h2>
<div class="entry-content">
   <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" /></a>
</div>
with border radius

<div class="entry-content">
    <a href="#" class="no-border"><img class="no-border" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" /></a>
</div>
without border radius
```

Also this is wrong

```
.entry-content img a
```

You cannot have an anchor tag as a child of an image tag.

Comment: you used `:not` in the first case and `.not` on the second... is this correct? Anyway I have tested both cases and they are not working

Answer (score 0):

Other users already solved your problem, but I want you to stay more aware about selectors.

```
.entry-content img withoutBorder, .entry-content img a withoutBorder
```

Matches this:

```
<div class="entry-content">
   ...
   <img>
     ...
     <withoutBorder></withoutBorder>
     ...
   </img>
   ...
</div>
```

Or this:

```
<div class="entry-content">
   ...
   <img>
     ...
     <a>
       ...
       <withoutBorder></withoutBorder>
       ...
     </a>
     ...
   </img>
   ...
</div>
```

Maybe you can read more about [selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)